# Want to pass last successful Team City build date to a Powershell script as a parameter

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a Team City build configuration that calls a powershell script via command line that executes a bunch of database scripts.

What I want to do is to pass a parameter to the command line that is the date of the last SUCCESSFUL build run for the configuration, so I can only execute the db scripts that have been modified since the last run.

I can't seem to find any way to do this. Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: why do you just pass the artifacts from the last successful build?

Comment: Well, I guess that is what I am basically asking how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the TeamCity REST API to get a list of last successful execution for your specific build. Then knowing the last successful build you can pull the date from the XML.

See here for API Details: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-BuildLocator